# installing andorid apps in BQ Aquaris E5 HD

Tags: 14.04, ubuntu-touch, phone, aquaris

How to install andoird apps in BQ Aquaris E5 ubuntu mobile. I just bought a mobile and don't know from where to install andorid apps other than ubuntu store. also i don't know from where to install firefox. is default browser is firefox or i have to install it. When i go to default browser it asks me to get it from  apple store when i click on it nothing happens ?
also Is there any quick start guide related to BQ or for developers etc. 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu touch is neither android nor iOS. Therefore, you cannot install android and iOS apps. Apps for Ubuntu touch can be installed through the ubuntu store.

Regarding firefox:
There is no firefox app for Ubuntu touch. You have to use the default browser or install [liri](https://uappexplorer.com/app/liri-browser.timsueberkrueb), an alternative web browser.

For developing apps, take a look at the [Ubuntu developer page](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/).